# GORM 2.0 get last insert ID

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

I'm operating on a MySQL database using **GORM v 2.0**. I'm inserting row into database using GORM transaction (`tx := db.Begin()`). In previous GORM versions, `Begin()` returned `sql.Tx` object that allowed to use `LastInsertId()` method on query return parameter.

To do that in GORM v 2.0, i can simply call `db.Last()` function after insert row into database, or i can use smarter method?

Thank you.

Comment: GORM 2.0 will set the `Id` inside the object automatically. Did you try it? Show your code otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In V2.0 the `GetLastInsertId` method was removed. As @rustyx says, the ID is populated in the model you pass the `Create` function. I wouldn't bother calling `db.Last(&...)` as this is a bit of a waste when the model will already have it.

```golang
    type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name string
    }

    user1 := User{Name: "User One"}

    _ = db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        tx.Create(&user1)
        return nil
    })

    // This is unnecessary
    // db.Last(&user1)

    fmt.Printf("User one ID: %d\n", user1.ID)
```